# SSRS Recursive Total of Child Row Amounts

Tags: sql-server, recursion, reporting-services, aggregate

I am working on a BOM tree explosion report. It's one of those things where it has a lot of uses that falls under one general idea: make it easy to visualize the BOM tree with information that the engineers and cost accountants care about. I'm working in SQL Server 2008r2 for MS Dynamics AX 2009.

The query runs fine. The report runs fine. The recursion runs fine. But what's missing is the weight rollup. In AX, the weight field is generally a convenience field in the item master that isn't usually used for any type of business logic. However, we use it as a factor in our CPQ software so it needs to be somewhat accurate. I'm trying to add visibility to the rollup of the weight to aid in the identification and correction of weights in our products.

Since I already have the weight per unit and the calculated total weight per BOM line in my dataset (and they are pulling correctly) my first attempts were to perform the aggregation in the SSRS report. I tried using `SUM(Fields!TotalWeight.Value, "BOMTreeDS", recursive)`, however, the result of that was that all of the BOM levels from the current row to all depths were subtotaled. So if my BOM has 5 {0,1,2,3,4} levels and I'm looking at something in level 2 then it will add the weights from this record in 2, its children in 3, and its children in 4 as well. This isn't good. The weights in 4 are already accounted for in level 3 and I definitely don't want to include the item's own weight.

So then I tried using a group variable named "GUID" in the one-and-only "Details" group that I am doing my recursion in. And I tried the formula `SUM(IIF(Variables!GUID.Value = Fields!PARENTGUID.Value, Fields!TotalWeight.Value, 0), "BOMTreeDS")`. I was pretty optimistic about this because it would return the sum of the weights for just the immediate children. I used the group variable because I wasn't sure how to manage the shift in scope from this row to all rows in the dataset inside of the IIF function. Anyway, it didn't work. Visual studio tells me that I am not allowed to use group variables inside of aggregate functions.

So then I shifted my attention to my SQL query in the dataset. If SSRS doesn't want to play nice I can get it done in SQL Server. I'm using a CTE to produce the recursion and I am creating GUIDs on the fly.

It's a pretty long query, but this is the fragment doing the BOM explosion...

```
WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT 
        CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS PARENTGUID,
        CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS GUID,
        PhysItem.*,
        CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ColorID,
        CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(28, 12)) AS BOMQTY,
        CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(28, 12)) AS QTY,
        0 AS Level
    FROM PhysItem
    WHERE 
        PhysItem.Item = @ItemId AND
        PhysItem.Color = @ColorId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CAST(Hierarchy.GUID AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS PARENTGUID,
        CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS GUID,
        PhysItem.DATAAREAID,
        PhysItem.Item,
        PhysItem.Color,
        PhysItem.ItemName,
        PhysItem.ItemGroup,
        PhysItem.ItemType,
        _Component.UNITID,
        CASE
                WHEN PhysItem.ItemGroup = 'PKG' OR PhysItem.ItemType = 'Service' THEN CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(28, 12))
                WHEN _Component.UNITID = 'lb' THEN 1
                ELSE PhysItem.NETWEIGHT
            END AS NETWEIGHT,
        CASE
                WHEN _Component.ITEMBOMID IS NOT NULL AND _Component.ITEMBOMID <> '' THEN _Component.BOMID
                ELSE PhysItem.BOMID
            END AS BOMID,
        _Invent.INVENTCOLORID,
        CAST(_Component.BOMQTY/_Component.BOMQTYSERIE AS NUMERIC(28, 12)),
        CAST(Hierarchy.QTY * _Component.BOMQTY/_Component.BOMQTYSERIE AS NUMERIC(28, 12)),
        Hierarchy.Level + 1
    FROM dbo.BOM _Component
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy ON
            _Component.BOMID            = Hierarchy.BOMID
            AND _Component.DATAAREAID   = Hierarchy.DATAAREAID
        INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTDIM _Invent ON
            _Component.INVENTDIMID      = _Invent.INVENTDIMID
            AND _Component.DATAAREAID   = _Invent.DATAAREAID
        INNER JOIN PhysItem ON
            Hierarchy.DATAAREAID        = PhysItem.DATAAREAID
            AND _Component.ITEMID       = PhysItem.Item
            AND _Invent.INVENTCOLORID   = PhysItem.Color
)
```

As you can see I am creating the GUIDs with CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(50)). Now I've got a new problem though. I created a subquery to sum the children and the comparisons from GUID to PARENTGUID are failing. This is particularly confusing for a few reasons.

1. I can see the values and I can see that they match.
2. I am casting the length of the NVARCHAR's at 50 so it shouldn't be a length issue.
3. SSRS is successfully matching the GUID's to the PARENTGUID's in the report and accurately depicting the BOM.

So yeah ... all of this to get a multilevel report of weights. In my mind, I'd like to see for each item the value that is currently set in the item master and the sum of the weights of the immediate children next to it. So then somebody can skim the report and say "hmmm... this weight doesn't look quite right".

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you could show simple before and after data to make it clear how the sums would work.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the best way to get tabular data in here is, but I'm thinking that if the top level item has a net weight of 40 and it has four components in it's active BOM and each one has a net weight of 35... then the evidence would indicate that the weight listed on the top level item is incorrect since the sum of its components is 140. This is an unrealistically simple example though since most of our BOMs have more than two levels.

Comment: [This](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) has some good ideas on creating tabular data for posting questions. Have a look then update your question.